# Undefined Index for ... existing index?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, undefined-index

OK, that's more than weird...

**Here's my code :**

```
public function results($id,$pattern=3)
{
    $this->load->library('session');

    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('return_url',$this->uri->uri_string());
        redirect('log/in','refresh');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('projects');

        $proj = (array)$this->projects->getProjectById($id);

        print_r($proj);

        $progressPercentage = number_format((float)( ($proj['progress'] * 100) / $proj['total'] ), 2, '.', '');

    }
}
```

**Now, here's the issue :**

- When NO `$pattern` is passed to the controller, the whole thing works fine.
- When I pass some parameter, like `mysite.com/project/results/45/4` (pattern=4), I'm getting the following error :

  ```
  A PHP Error was encountered

  Severity: Notice

  Message: Undefined index: progress

  Filename: controllers/project.php

  Line Number: 75
  ```

The weird thing is that both `$id` and `$pattern` are "read" fine.

When I'm `print_r`ing `$proj` just before the line concerning `undefined index` this the results I'm getting :

> Array ( [id] => 21240 [email] => my@gmail.com [url] => somewebsite.com [domains] => another_domain [progress] => 198 [total]
>   => 199 [alias] => Test Project #3 [status] => complete )

And well as you can obviously see for yourself, the `progress` index is perfectly there.

So, what could the issue be? Is that any weird know CI bug?

---

This is what `var_dump($proj,$proj['progress']);` gives :

```
array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(5) "21240"
  ["email"]=>
  string(20) "my@gmail.com"
  ["url"]=>
  string(27) "somewebsite.com"
  ["domains"]=>
  string(84) "another_domain"
  ["progress"]=>
  string(3) "198"
  ["total"]=>
  string(3) "199"
  ["alias"]=>
  string(15) "Test Project #3"
  ["status"]=>
  string(8) "complete"
}
string(3) "198"
```

Comment: What is outputted if writing `var_dump($proj, $proj['progress']);` instead of the `print_r($proj);`?

Comment: @smhnaji Have a look, I re-edited the original question.

Comment: Also note that it's not just `progress` it can't find. It cannot see **any** index... :S

Comment: I know it's very dirty, but what happens if you `$progress = $proj['progress'];` and use $progress in the next line's function?

Comment: Only Undefined index: progress? or total index undefined error?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon `$progressPercentage = number_format((float)( ($proj['progress'] * 100) / $proj['total'] ), 2, '.', '');` is this line number 75?

Comment: Can you paste getProjectById() function? This issue about $pattern

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
mysite.com/CONTROLLER/results/45/4
```

Comment: I just mistyped it in the question. It's exactly as you say.